# dplyr if_else Error: `true` must be length x (length of `condition`) or one, not 0 in r

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame('Home.Team'=c("Omaha South", "Millard North", "Elkhorn","Elkhorn"),                      
                 'Winner'=c("Omaha South", "Millard North", "Elkhorn","Elkhorn"),
                 'Won By'=c(8,22,4,30),
                 'Away Class'=c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE"))
```

I'm trying to create a new column/variable using conditional `if_else` from `dplyr`. This had worked for me in the past but for some reason it is now giving me an error. Below is the r code and error:

```
df$'Pre Score' <- 
        if_else(df$`Away Class`=="FALSE", 
        if_else(df$Home.Team==df$Winner, .8 + (df$`Won By`/100) -1, -1.2 - (df$`Won By`/100) -1), 
        if_else(df$Home.Team==df$Winner, .8 + (df$`Won By`/100), -1.2 - (df$`Won By`/100)))
```

*Error: `true` must be length 4 (length of `condition`) or one, not 0*

I've read through multiple SO discussions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476699/why-does-dplyr-error-in-this-nested-if-else-when-logical-condition-means-output), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308673/error-message-when-using-mutate-function-in-r), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292792/3-conditional-statement-throws-a-length-error-in-r)) related to this but haven't been able to translate it into a solution for my problem. It seem to have something to do with the "if true" portion of the code. Apparently it thinks this is a length of one whereas I want it to be a length of 4, or to work for all rows. Tried replacing if_else with case_when but wasn't able to succeed there either.

Comment: Not directly related, but why do you have true & false as characters and not boolean values? For debugging ifelse statements, especially ones nested like this, it would be a good idea to pick them apart one by one to see which ones do or don't run. Also, how did you try `case_when`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should have been a comment, but it came out too confusing:

You're missing periods in your variable names - data.frame automatically adds those when you create a df with variable names that have spaces:

```
if_else(df$`Away.Class`=="FALSE", #Away.Class instead of `Away Class`
             if_else(df$Home.Team==df$Winner, .8 + (df$`Won.By`/100) -1, -1.2 - (df$`Won.By`/100) -1), # Won.By instead of `Won By`
             if_else(df$Home.Team==df$Winner, .8 + (df$`Won.By`/100), -1.2 - (df$`Won.By`/100))) # ditto
[1] 0.88 0.02 0.84 0.10
```

Here's why your code results in an error: when you run `.8 + (df$`Won By`/100) -1`, the result is `NULL`, because the column doesn't exist - so the list TRUE/FALSE results is length zero. `ifelse` needs this list to either be the same length as your condition (which is four, in which case each TRUE case will get it appropriate data), or 1 (in which case all TRUE results will get the same output).

Comment: Thanks @iod. Will this solve the issue above or is that and additional error?

Comment: As I show in my example - if I run the code with the missing periods, I get the expected answer (`[1] 0.88 0.02 0.84 0.10`)